# Please help building ladosc on 64bit raring

Tags: compiling, shared-library, ld

This is a question for the code savy, which I'm not...
I'm trying to build a set of oldish ladspa plug-ins called ladosc (you can find them on [google-code](http://code.google.com/p/noisesmith-linux-audio/downloads/detail?name=ladosc.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)) but there are errors I can't find a workaround for.

The Makefile:

```
    DESTINATION_DIR=~/.ladspa
    LIBLO_STATIC=/usr/lib/liblo.a

    install: install_op install_osc
    install_op: op.so
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_DIR}
    cp op.so ${DESTINATION_DIR}/.ladspa
    op.so: operator.o
    ld operator.o -o op.so -shared
    operator.o: operator.c
    gcc -c operator.c
    install_osc: osc.so
    mkdir -p ${DESTINATION_DIR}
    cp osc.so ${DESTINATION_DIR}/.ladspa
    osc.so: osc.o ${LIBLO_STATIC}
    ld osc.o ${LIBLO_STATIC} -o osc.so -shared
    osc.o: lad-osc.c
    gcc -c -g lad-osc.c -o osc.o
    clean:
    rm *.o *~ *.so
```

There is no configure script and when I make, the linker throws the following error:

```
ld: operator.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
operator.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

When I add -fPIC flags to the gcc calls in the makefile the build runs differently and the linker gives the following error:

```
ld osc.o /usr/lib/liblo.a -o osc.so -shared
ld: /usr/lib/liblo.a(liblo_la-address.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against     `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/liblo.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I do not understand this. Does it mean I have to recompile liblo? It is taken directly from the Ubunut repos.

These issues have been raised already by someone else on the project pages on google code about 3 years ago but the developer didn't react.

I already searched for explanations and found lots of stuff about position independent code and differences between 32bit and 64bit but I don't understand enough to find a solution for my problem.

Can anybody help me to get these plug-ins up and running?

Cheers,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the developer and he helped me compiling it.

I had to replace the `liblo.a` with `liblo.so` (.so is a shared lib and .a is not) in the makefile and compile with `-fPIC` flags for gcc.

Now the plug-ins compile. Couldn't test them functionally, yet, but they open fine in Ardour.